# Getting memory leak at NSURL connection in Iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory-leaks

Here Im getting leak at the NSURL connection in my libxml parser can anyone tell how to resolve it.

The code where leak generates is:

```
- (BOOL)parseWithLibXML2Parser
{
BOOL success = NO;
ZohoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ZohoAppDelegate*) [ [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString* curl;
if ([cName length] == 0) 
{
curl = @"https://invoice.zoho.com/api/view/settings/currencies?ticket=";
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:appDelegate.ticket];
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:@"&apikey="];
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:appDelegate.apiKey];
curl = [curl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];    
}
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:curl]];

NSLog(@"the request parserWithLibXml2Parser %@",theRequest);
NSURLConnection *con = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self] autorelease];//Memory leak generated here at this line of code.

//self.connection = con;
//[con release];
// This creates a context for "push" parsing in which chunks of data that are 
// not "well balanced" can be passed to the context for streaming parsing. 
// The handler structure defined above will be used for all the parsing. The
// second argument, self, will be passed as user data to each of the SAX
// handlers. The last three arguments are left blank to avoid creating a tree
// in memory.
_xmlParserContext = xmlCreatePushParserCtxt(&simpleSAXHandlerStruct, self, NULL, 0, NULL);
if(con != nil) 
{
    do 
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    } while (!_done && !self.error);
}
if(self.error)
{
    //NSLog(@"parsing error");
    [self.delegate parser:self encounteredError:nil];
} else 
{
    success = YES;
}
return success;
}
```

Anyone's help will be muck appreciated .

Thank you,
Monish.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try releasing `theRequest` seems like it will be copied in the `NSURLConnection` init which increases the retain count. Another try would be handle the memory management of `con` by yourself

Comment: `theRequest` shouldn't need to be released as it was created by a convenience method, and not retained.